How to give a PNG (image texture) some sheen/ gloss?
I'm trying to make a sticker (PNG file) and they tend to generally have a plastic film on top that makes them look glossy.

At first, I tried to modify the principal BSDF node by setting roughness to 0 and tried playing around with sheen and coat. I got no gloss from it so I tried something else, currently looks like this:

which hasnt been helpful either. Is there any way to get some glossy layer over my image?
Edit: my light setup (there's also an HDRI but I might change that at some point)


Sheen is for fabric or dust. Do you have anything to reflect in your scene and show the coat ?

@Lutzi I've included a basic lighting setup in the edit. I also have an HDRI in, which I may change later when finalising the scene.
Should I set the coat weight to 1 and add a light for the stickers when I create the environment?

Having an HDRI or lights won't be enough in itself : do you have something bright on the part that is reflected through the stickers reflection ? For your question, basically yes, set Coat Weight to 1, then either move your camera to get a light reflection, or move your lights & HDRI. Then you can tweak the coat down if it's too strong. Coat is exactly what you want, it's a thin layer on top of the material (which can be rough) : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#layers

@Lutzi thank you! Exactly what I needed
